# Unity: How do I get the boundary positions from a placed quad in AR?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, position, augmented-reality

I want to spawn objects on random positions within a placed quad in AR. Basically, it should look like it the objects get spawned from the quad which plays the role of a "ground".

I have a placement indicator implemented which places a quad in the world when tapping on the screen. After some seconds the spawn process is initiated and random objects are spawned. However the positioning of the objects are never right. They are never within the quad boundaries and additionally are often way above the placed quad (whereas the intention is - concerning the y axis - that they are placed exactly **on** the quad).

What did I do wrong and how can I find the right positions?

This scripts is attached to the ground prefab I created which is spawned through a script called `ARTapToPlaceObjects`. The ground placement works fine, so I didn't include that script.

```
public class SpawnObjects : MonoBehaviour
{
    private ARTapToPlaceObjects groundPlacement;
    private Vector3 groundDimMin;
    private Vector3 groundDimMax;

    public GameObject[] gamePieces;
    private GameObject spawnObject;

    private float waitSpawnTime = 5f;
    public int maxSpawns = 13;

    private void Awake()
    {
        groundPlacement = FindObjectOfType<ARTapToPlaceObjects>();
        groundDimMin = GetComponent<MeshCollider>().bounds.min;
        groundDimMax = GetComponent<MeshCollider>().bounds.max;
        Debug.Log("max: " + groundDimMax + "min: " + groundDimMin);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        Debug.Log("start checking ground: " + groundPlacement.GroundSet());
        if (groundPlacement.GroundSet())
        {
            if (maxSpawns > 0)
            {
                Debug.Log(maxSpawns);

                Debug.Log("start spawning on ground");
                StartCoroutine(SpawningRandomObjects());
            }
        }
    }
    
private Vector3 RandomPosition()
    {
        float x = Random.Range(Mathf.Abs(groundDimMin.x), Mathf.Abs(groundDimMax.x));
        float y = Random.Range(Mathf.Abs(groundDimMin.y), Mathf.Abs(groundDimMax.y));
        float z = Random.Range(Mathf.Abs(groundDimMin.z), Mathf.Abs(groundDimMax.z));

        return new Vector3(x, y, z);
    }

    private IEnumerator SpawningRandomObjects()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(waitSpawnTime);

        Vector3 randomPosition = RandomPosition();
        Debug.Log("randomPos: " + randomPosition.ToString());

        Instantiate(RandomGamePiece(gamePieces), randomPosition, Quaternion.identity);
        Debug.Log("instantiated at: " + randomPosition.ToString());
        maxSpawns--;

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(Random.Range(1f, waitSpawnTime));
    }
```

In `RandomPosition()` I initially had the floats without `Mathf.Abs`, but then I realized while debugging that the spawned positions often have negative values, so I tried it with absolute values, but this however resulted in not seeing the spawned objects at all (not seen in 'real world' but are spawned since I see the debug texts)